# Laravel 5.5 dependency injection with constructor methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection

I have created a service in app/services/KDataService.php that looks like this:

```
class KDataService
{
    /** @var  string */
    private $license;

    /** @var  string */
    private $owner;

    /** @var string  */
    private $accessToken;

    public function __construct($owner, $license)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
        $this->license = $license;

        ...

    }

       ...

}
```

In one of my controller I try to inject this service with the dependency injection pattern but I get the following error:

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $owner ]] in class App\Services\KDataService

My controller:

```
use App\Services\KDataService;

class DamagePointController extends Controller
{
    /** @var  KDataService $kDataService */
    private $kDataService;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param KDataService $kDataService
     */
    public function __construct(KDataService $kDataService)
    {
        $this->kDataService = $kDataService;
    }  

    ...

}
```

Anyone knows how I can pass my $owner and $license?

Comment: Laravel version?

Comment: @FreeLightman 5.5, I'll edit OP too

Comment: What are the `$owner` and `$licence` types? Laravel don't know what to inject to build your `KDataService`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your service has arguments but you don't specify them. There are several ways to do this.

**Using service provider**:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Riak\Connection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class kDataServiceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(KDataService::class, function ($app) {
            return new KDataService(getOwner(), getLicense());
        });
    }
}
```

`bind` could be change to other methods. See [Service Container docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container).

**Using app to make instanse**:

```
/* Controller __construct */
$this->kDataService = \App::make(KDataService::class, [getOwner(), getLicense()]);
```

**Simply create class instance**

```
/* Controller __construct */
$this->kDataService = new KDataService(getOwner(), getLicense());
```

*Note*: `getOwner and getLicense` change to your logic. Usually you can retrieve it within controller or from `$app`.

Generally what you need to resolve the issue is to read about service container and service providers in docs.